# json array split to multiple arrays

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I am reading the contents of an api ('https://myapi.com/allcolor') into a dataframe using the pyspark code below in azure databricks notebook. When I read the json content into dataframe somehow the json payload with one **"colors"** array is getting translated to multiple arrays.

**Code:**

```
spark.sql("set spart.databricks.delta.preview.enabled=true")
spark.sql("set spart.databricks.delta.retentionDutationCheck.preview.enabled=false")
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import pandas as pd
user = "username"
password = "password"
myResponse = requests.get('https://myapi.com/allcolor', auth=(user, password))
if(myResponse.ok):
  jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)
  s1 = json.dumps(jData)
  #load data from api
  x = json.loads(s1)
  data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(x))
  #create dataframe
  spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
  spark_df.show()          
  spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net","<your-storage-account-access-key>")
  spark_df.write.mode("overwrite").json("wasbs://<container>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory>/")
else:
  myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

**Source json payload:**

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          255,
          255,
          255,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          255,
          0,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          0,
          0,
          255,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#00F"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          255,
          255,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#FF0"
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          0,
          255,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#0F0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Resultant dataframe:**

```
{
  "colors": 
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          255,
          255,
          255,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    }
    }
{
  "colors":     
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "hex": "#FFF"
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does `json.dumps(x)` look like the source file?

Comment: Hi @Kris, No `json.dumps(x)` has multiple arrays.

Comment: `jData` is same as source.

Comment: If `jData` is correct, then for me `pd.DataFrame(jData['colors'])` seems to work.

Comment: Hi @Kris, `pd.DataFrame(jData['colors'])` still gives me multiple arrays.

Comment: So I let `jData` = your source `json`, and I get this: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8460/Pxr3mx.png. Is this your intended dataframe output?

Comment: I tried `df=spark.createDataFrame([Row(**i) for i in data])` throws `TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str`. `df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([data]))` throws `df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]`.

Comment: Hi @Kris, I want 1 colors array same as the source json api payload with all the underlying elements.